# apt upgrade failing: unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, server, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server. Recently I attempted to update it. I was met with this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I did what it said to, which did not help

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/28.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried the solutions I found to no avail.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Rebooting didn't help either.
If anyone could help or has any idea what might be creating this issue I would be very grateful. This server is kinda important to me. DNS, file sharing, movies, all that fun stuff runs off it.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the latest /var/log/apt/term.log that had content in it

```
Log started: 2020-11-25  20:32:55

dpkg: systemd-timesyncd: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 systemd depends on systemd-timesyncd | time-daemon; however:
  Package systemd-timesyncd is to be removed.
  Package time-daemon is not installed.
  Package systemd-timesyncd which provides time-daemon is to be removed.
 systemd depends on systemd-timesyncd | time-daemon; however:
  Package systemd-timesyncd is to be removed.
  Package time-daemon is not installed.
  Package systemd-timesyncd which provides time-daemon is to be removed.

(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 197964 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ...
```

The log doesn't contain an end. The next log starts 17 days later.
Also IDK why it was trying to remove systemd-timesyncd...

UPDATE: I tried to reinstall systemd-timesyncd and got this error
`systemd-timesyncd is already the newest version (245.4-4ubuntu3.3).`
it says that whether I `apt install` or `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: You need to fix two items: "*1 not fully installed or removed*" and "*47 not upgraded*". This has clearly been going on for a while. We can offer better advice if you recall what happened when the issue began and you started to encounter lots of error messages. Your `var/log/apt/term.log` likely has the complete record of what happened.

Comment: `/var/log/apt/term.log` doesn't contain anything useful, just ```Log started: 2020-12-04  00:15:07
Log ended: 2020-12-04  00:15:07
```

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, that was a mistake, I will extract the older records and post them in the original question

Comment: Well, *somebody* was manually mucking about with time-related packages on your system on 25 November. If not you, then perhaps you have an intrusion problem instead of an apt problem?

Comment: IDK. I don't think I have someone on my server that I don't know about, and the people I do know about shouldn't be messing with APT. Which leaves me. I could have done it, but what convinced me to do that? And forget it? IDK. Anyways, do you know how to repair this package?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the `systemd-timesyncd` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had too `sudo apt reinstall systemd-timesyncd`. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a ton friend. I spent countless hours trying to fix this, downloading all dependencies by .deb and trying to install didn't help... and then this one command fixed it all, amazing!